# wireless drops out on Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 (rev 01) with a Mini 300M USB WiFi Wireless LAN 802.11 n/g/b Adapter

Tags: wireless, internet

basically when i use internet it is fine, however if i stop actively browsing or downloading my connection drops out. I still have the connection to the router but no internet. Other devices can still connect to that router and get internet. Anyone has any idea what this is?

Comment: The RTL8111 is an ethernet card, not wireless. Please edit your question to add details of your wireless card from the terminal: lspci -nn | grep 0280

Comment: my apologies! what i meant to say is i have a Mini 300M USB WiFi Wireless LAN 802.11 n/g/b Adapter and it keeps dropping the connection but if i disconnect and connect to the network again it works for another few minutes. This only happens on Linux i havent had this problem with Windows.

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless card from the terminal: lsusb